# Error while trying https authentication in Python 2.7

Tags: python, http-authentication

Getting this Error while trying https authentication in Python 2.7

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>python virustotal.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "virustotal.py", line 5, in <module>
    response=requests.post('http://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/scan',files=files,params=params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 107, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 53, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 437, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.virustotal.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /vtapi/v2/file/scan?apikey=1906752e0d41eba10eb09cdadd0f3abcc26cb74c04d1c9450
dfd0ff8894b81da (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x02C6DAB0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed',))
```

Comment: do you have any proxies set up in your system or environment!

Comment: yes. we have proxy. @praba230890